# ¿De que forma se puede establecer un servicio de Windows como interactivo en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

He estado probando una funcionalidad en un servicio de Windows la cual se pueda comunicar con el usuario directamente por medio de una aplicación o GUI para comunicarse con el servicio, por lo cual la funcionalidad de un servicio interactivo solo está disponible desde el Administrador de servicios > en el cuadro de diálogo en la hoja de propiedades > en la pestaña de Inicio de sesión, específicamente en la casilla de verificación de '*Permitir que el servicio interactúe con el escritorio'*, por lo cual mi propósito es aplicar esta funcionalidad desde Python sin necesidad de acceder a las propiedades del servicio.

**Nota:** También intenté usando los parámetros de la línea de comandos de `sc.exe config`en  `type = interact type = own` pero solo puedo establecer como *verdadero* el servicio como interactivo pero no puedo deshacer la acción a *falso*.

También he leído la documentación oficial de servicios interactivos proporcionado por Microsoft y establece la marca SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS, la cual hace referencia a una constante predefinida que se usa para representar un valor que es pasado o devuelto en este caso como servicio interactivo, aunque se puede aplicar de manera programática en C++ en la función `CreateServiceA()` en `dwServiceType`, no encuentro la manera de aplicar estos parámetros en Python. Si es proporcionada una respuesta que se adecue a la pregunta se lo agradecería.

Comment: Puede también revisar la documentación de la librería [wmi](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html), ahí puede encontrar muchas funcionalidades para los servicios de Windows adaptados a la programación en Python.

Comment: Gracias por el enlace suministrado, la librería wmi puede funcionar en mi caso para la configuración de servicios de Windows, aunque usted de casualidad sabría cómo puedo establecer el parámetro como interactivo en el servicio en wmi?

Comment: Para eso usted debe revisar el formato que utiliza WMI el cuál es un modelo de objetos MOF en CIM donde usted encuentra dentro de una determinada clase  espacios de nombres con funcionalidades de esa clase. Puede consultar este enlace de Microsoft sobre los [servicios](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para dar una respuesta a esta pregunta, con WMI puede importar la clase `Win32_Service()`, al importar esta clase usted puede aplicar el parámetro del espacio de nombres `DesktopInteract` en verdadero para el servicio seleccionado, esto mediante el método de cambiar o `Change()`. Esto en resumen, es posible representarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
serviceVar = wmi.WMI() # Retomar e iniciar la librería
for serviceState in serviceVar.Win32_Service(Name = 'miServicio'):
    serviceState.Change(DesktopInteract = True) # Establecer en verdadero como servicio interactivo
```

> Tenga en cuenta que utilizando un bucle `for`/`in` usted importa como variable el espacio de nombres. `Name`, se utiliza para el nombre del servicio o también `Caption`.

**Nota:** Establecer un servicio como interactivo es una técnica un poco obsoleta y no es recomendable por la probabilidad de tener riesgos de seguridad ya que los servicios no están destinados a proporcionar una interfaz de usuario ni permitir ningún tipo de interacción directa con el usuario.